# Unable To Upgrade SonarQube 6.1 - Error at row during uuid path upgrade

Tags: sonarqube, upgrade, sonarqube-ops

I got the following exception during upgrade from **sonar 6.1** from `5.6.3` LTS. 
As far as I understood I've a problem with database but I am unable to figure out what is the problem with the given row, currently searching related source code to find something.

```
2016.10.14 18:34:40 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during processing of row: [uuid=AVS4o0LOzu3ZyQatBmI3,project_uuid=AVS4ov1WdZ1hgUI96lxc]
    at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.newExceptionWithRowDetails(SelectImpl.java:89) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:81) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.MassUpdate.execute(MassUpdate.java:91) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.handleRoot(PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.java:83) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.execute(PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.java:60) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.BaseDataChange.execute(BaseDataChange.java:45) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migrations.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(DatabaseMigrator.java:95) ~[sonar-server-6.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:455) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:61) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::Migration$$migrate_18492D5320618EC94E0F22A95C6CD80EEFB6A64D39344204.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit$ActiveRecord::Migration$$migrate_18492D5320618EC94E0F22A95C6CD80EEFB6A64D39344204$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActiveRecord::Migration$$migrate_18492D5320618EC94E0F22A95C6CD80EEFB6A64D39344204$block_0$RUBY$__file__) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.Benchmark$$measure_5AD958E31099104265C835112D1C30E23EEF72B139344204.__file__(jar:file:/opt/sonarqube-6.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.Benchmark$$measure_5AD958E31099104265C835112D1C30E23EEF72B139344204.__file__(jar:file:/opt/sonarqube-6.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:38) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:193) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.WrapperMethod.call(WrapperMethod.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::Migration$$migrate_18492D5320618EC94E0F22A95C6CD80EEFB6A64D39344204.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::Migration$$migrate_18492D5320618EC94E0F22A95C6CD80EEFB6A64D39344204.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:201) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:567) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2595) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2227) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:356) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:213) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:217) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:114) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::MigrationProxy$$migrate_F82210E5123BB0207C1ADAC1D40F1F34A4C5A16739344204.chained_0_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:365) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::MigrationProxy$$migrate_F82210E5123BB0207C1ADAC1D40F1F34A4C5A16739344204.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::MigrationProxy$$migrate_F82210E5123BB0207C1ADAC1D40F1F34A4C5A16739344204.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:42) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:224) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:202) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::Migrator$$ddl_transaction_3154E5716AE12F6E5915C8C10138A66869AC914C39344204.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:576) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.ActiveRecord::Migrator$$ddl_transaction_3154E5716AE12F6E5915C8C10138A66869AC914C39344204.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-6.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:357) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:312) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1606) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1613) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgNode.java:38) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.WhenOneArgNode.whenNoTest(WhenOneArgNode.java:27) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.WhenOneArgNode.when(WhenOneArgNode.java:45) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CaseNode.interpret(CaseNode.java:132) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:164) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at RbCallUpgrade_734243340.callUpgrade(RbCallUpgrade_734243340.gen:13) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doUpgradeDb(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:126) ~[sonar-server-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doDatabaseMigration(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:108) ~[sonar-server-6.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects$Snapshot.access$300(PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.java:137) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.lambda$handleComponent$4(PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.java:120) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.stream.LongPipeline$3$1.accept(LongPipeline.java:231) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.Spliterators$LongArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1115) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfLong.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:757) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.handleComponent(PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.java:121) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.lambda$handleRoot$2(PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects.java:83) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.MassUpdate.callSingleHandler(MassUpdate.java:117) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.MassUpdate.lambda$execute$0(MassUpdate.java:91) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:78) ~[sonar-db-6.1.jar:na]
    ... 144 common frames omitted
2016.10.14 18:34:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB migration failed | time=7408190ms
2016.10.14 18:34:40 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v60.PopulateUuidPathColumnOnProjects
```

Comment: what is your database and which version?

Comment: @Yusuf-TAMBAĞ did you find a solution? I hit the same problem today. Also while updating from 5.6.3 to 6.1

Answer (score 0):

This problem is tracked by https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8391 and will be resolved in SonarQube 6.2 (which is to be released in the upcoming weeks at the time of this writing).